# Why do self made symlinks/aliases in /usr/local/bin not work as expected with 'which' command?

Tags: bash, macos, symlink, bin

I've been creating bash scripts recently, and would like to store them in my `/usr/local/bin` directory. When I `ls` this directory, I see many, what I believe to be, symlink paths. Example:

```
brew -> /usr/local/HomeBrew/bin/brew
```

I've been able to successfully create symlinks to my own scripts and stored them in my `/usr/local/bin` with the `ln` command:

```
ln -s /User/me/Projects/bash/my_script /usr/local/bin/my_script
```

and everything runs as expected.

The problem I'm encountering, is when I to try run `which my_script` it's not returning a nice stdout result, like it is with the other scripts. For example running `which brew` returns: `/usr/local/bin/brew` in a nice stdout format to use with other commands.

Running `which my_script`, will successfully detect my script but, returns

```
my_script: aliased to ~/Projects/bash/my_script
```

This makes combining with other commands more difficult.

Can anyone explain what the difference is, and how I could possibly fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set an `alias` for `my_script` in your `.zshrc`? That's what it appears like.

Comment: @I'L'I This is tagged [tag:bash] and the question mentions Bash repeatedly; so probably `.bash_profile` and/or `.bashrc`

Comment: I thought it might be that, but have checked and I removed any alias to my script from my .bashrc, and have re-sourced it:/ so don't think it's that.

Answer (score 1):

You must have defined an alias named `my_script`, which is shadowing your symbolic link. You can do a

```
type -a my_script
```

to find all definitions. To bypass the alias, invoke it using

```
command my_script
```

Aside from this: Are you sure that you really want a link from `/usr/local/bin` into something which is below your `/User/me`? This does not look sane to me. Wouldn't it be better to simply put `/User/me/Projects/bash` into your PATH?

Comment: So when I run ```type -a my_script``` I get a long list of paths, the first one being what I mentioned above. ```my_script is an alias for /Users/me/Documets etc...``` How would you recommend I add to PATH? (I'm working in bash, .bashrc etc.)

Comment: First, delete the alias definition. Then, put it into your startup files, where you likely already contain other directories to your PATH. Depending to your usage of bash, `~/.bash_profile`, respectively `~/.bashrc`, could be sensible choices. Read in the bash man page the section titles _INVOCATION_, which explains which files bash processes automatically under which circumstances.